# Jquery for getting values of h2 tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
//banner + page title for the About Us page..
<div id="pageSpecificBanners"><h2 class="page-Title">about us</h2></div>

//banner + page title for the Practices page..
<div id="pageSpecificBanners"><h2 class="page-Title">practices</h2></div>
```

How would i go about getting the value of the h2 tags for each of the pages in jquery...

so that  if the value of h2 tag is equal to "about us" I would like to append another  tag to the "pageSpecificBanners" div like so:

```
$('div#PageSpecificBanners').append('<h2 class="printOnlyPage-Title">about us</h2>');
```

then equally if the value of the H2 tag is equal to "practices", I would like to append another  tag to the "pageSpecifiBanner" div like so:

```
$('div#PageSpecificBanners').append('<h2 class="printOnlyPage-Title2">practices');
```

Essentially I want to add additional h2 tags for print Only purposes...

Many thanks,

Comment: why don't you simply add a print class to the existant h2 elements? Why you need to have the same title duplicated for styling purposes?

Comment: if your sample code is not just a sample, you're reusing the same ID for multiple elements, which will not do any good for your website, its rating and the code

Comment: The reason I am taking the long wan and adding additional H2 tags is because currently the text font color which is set to #fff for the screen, for some reason comes out grey when printing the page. I have tried to force the #fff font color for printing but it always comes out grey... I hope to get different results by using this long approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var value = $("#pageSpecificBanners h2").html();

if(value == "about me")
    $('div#PageSpecificBanners')
        .append('<h2 class="printOnlyPage-Title">about us</h2>');
else if(h2 == "practices")
    $('div#PageSpecificBanners')
        .append('<h2 class="printOnlyPage-Title2">practices');
```

Comment: I have tried the above approach but it's not working. The actual html I have is: <div id="PageSpecificBanners"><img src="/img/aboutus.png" /><h2 class="page-title">about us</h2></div>. So could the reason that it is not working be because of the <img> tag before the h2 tag?

Comment: Sorry this does work... I had contain the H2 tag withing another Div. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var h2 = $('<h2 class="printOnlyPage-Title"></h2>').text($('div#PageSpecificBanners h2').text());
$('div#PageSpecificBanners').append(h2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for text, add an extra class in addition to page-Title:

```
<div id="pageSpecificBanners"><h2 class="page-Title about-us">about us</h2></div>
```

and the code becomes

```
if($("#pageSpecificBanners .page-Title").hasclass("about-us")){
    $('div#PageSpecificBanners').append('<h2 class="printOnlyPage-Title">about us</h2>');
}
```

and similarly for practices. I'd avoid comparing the inner text - you'll need to remember where all to fix if the text changes.